# Covering map, singular homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces and $q:Y\rightarrow X$ a covering map with $|q^{⁻1}({x} )|=n$ for all $x \in X$. I want to show that the induced map $$H_k(q,\mathbb{Q}):H_k(Y,\mathbb{Q})\rightarrow H_k(X,\mathbb{Q})$$ is surjective for all $k$. I am not sure where to start and would be grateful for any idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**A start:** Let $\Delta$ be a closed $1$-simplex in $X$, in other words $\Delta:[0,1]\to X$ with $\Delta(0)=\Delta(1)$, and let $\overline{\Delta}_i$, $i=1,\ldots, n$ denote the various lifts of $\Delta$ to $Y$. $\overline{\Delta}_i$ is not necessarily closed, but we know that $q(\overline{\Delta}(0))=q(\overline{\Delta}(1))$. Show that $\sum_i\overline{\Delta}_i$ is closed, and so $$n[\Delta]\in\mathrm{Im}(H_1(q,\mathbb{Z})).$$It follows that $$[\Delta]\in\mathrm{Im}(H_1(q,\mathbb{Q})).$$

Comment: Thank you. In our lecture we defined a 1-simplex in x as a continuous map $f:|\Delta^1|\rightarrow X$ where $|\Delta^1|:=\{(x,y) \in [0,1]\times [0,1] | x+y=1\}$.

Comment: @guest1991 Surely you'll agree that $|\Delta^1|$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$ and so my answer can work with your definition.

Comment: This is the way the proof works in any dimension as well.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval Does your argument on $[\Delta]\in \text{Im}(H_1(q,\mathbb{Q}))$ works with homology of integer coefficients?